# How do you set a JavaScript variable when a link is clicked (to open a specific part of a popup)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a link that shows a glossary popup when you click it. It should run a script that changes the variable "WordId" to the html element id of the heading that corresponds to the definition of the word.

I tried this:

```
<a onclick="BrowserPopupGlossary()" onclick="WordId = "...";">...</a>
```

This is the BrowserPopupGlossary function:

```
var WordId;
function BrowserPopupGlossary() {
    window.open('glossary.html'+'#'+WordId,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=400')
}
```

Any advice on how to optimize / fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that value is known at all at that time then just pass it to the function.  There's no need for a global variable here, and certainly no need to try and create two `onclick` handlers.

For example:

```
<a onclick="BrowserPopupGlossary('someValue')">...</a>
```

And use it in the function:

```
function BrowserPopupGlossary(wordId) {
  window.open('glossary.html#' + wordId, 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=400');
}
```

Comment: why thank you! so I guess kinda like Sass mixin variables. Solved!